# How to use substring in criteriaQuery api (jpa 2.0)

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm trying to do a substring query using jpa 2.0 but I dont know how to do this.
Until now I have this code:

```
time = builder.between(
                matchesRoot.<Integer>get("startDateTime").toString().substring(8, 13),
                Integer.getInteger(DateTimeUtil.dateTimeWithoutFormat(searchCommercialsDTO.getFinalDate())),
                Integer.getInteger(DateTimeUtil.dateTimeWithoutFormat(searchCommercialsDTO.getIniDate()))
                );
```

But it isn't working since I cant compile it becouse of this error:

> no suitable method found for between(String,Integer,Integer)
>       method CriteriaBuilder.between(Expression,Y#1,Y#1) is not applicable
>         (no instance(s) of type variable(s) Y#1 exist so that argument type String conforms to formal parameter type Expression)
>       method CriteriaBuilder.between(Expression,Expression,Expression) is not applicable
>         (no instance(s) of type variable(s) Y#2 exist so that argument type String conforms to formal parameter type Expression)
>     where Y#1,Y#2 are type-variables:
>       Y#1 extends Comparable declared in method between(Expression,Y#1,Y#1)
>       Y#2 extends Comparable declared in method between(Expression,Expression,Expression

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Substring can be used via [CriteriaBuilder.substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#substring%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29). That of course does not operate to integer, but to string.

In current approach you are calling toString method of [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html). There is no connection between substring function in resulting SQL and toString method of class that is used to build query.